# Android KSOAP2 call ASMX Web Service

Tags: android, asmx, ksoap2

class wsCall extends AsyncTask {

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/PrivateLogin";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "PrivateLogin";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.110/omoffice/service/wsomjobs.asmx";        
private Context mContext;   

public wsCall (Context context){
     mContext = context;
}

 @Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
}

protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
{   
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("userid","poma");           
    request.addProperty("pw","1");
    request.addProperty("azienda","1");

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER10);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);             
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);               
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        return "OK";
```

In androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope) I obtain this error: **java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream**

Someone help me?

thanks
Marco

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure if `SOAP` version you are using is 10??

try using `SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();` instead of `SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;`

Comment: I tried but the error is before this line. I obtain error in : androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope).

Comment: Try changing this line `SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER10);` as `SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);`